# Correct syntax for a js function call

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to call a javascript function:

`onclick='loadData("<%=entry.getDisplayName()%>","<%=moduleVal%>","<%=entry.getFileDesc()%>","<%=entry.getFileID()%>")'>`

The aim is to convert the array of string from java notation to javascript notation and pass it to the function for further processing.

This is the `modVal` declaration part:

`<% String moduleVal = getArrayString(entry.getModuleName()); %>`

This is the `getArrayString` declaration:

```
<%!
     public static String getArrayString(String[] items){
        String result = "[";
        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            result += "\"" + items[i] + "\"";
            if(i < items.length - 1) {
                result += ", ";
            }
        }
        result += "]";

        return result;
    }
    %>
```

This is the error I am getting:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

This is the code that gets generated on execution:

loadData("Penguins_1","["Module 2"]","1113","1")

I am lost here. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `"["Module 2"]"` is not a legal `String` literal in Java.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It is an parameter to js function.

Comment: This is seen  as `loadData(String,StringModule 2String,String,String)`, You need to escape the `"` around Module2 to be seen as a String (well an string representation of an array.

Comment: Yes exactly. But, I could not figure out a way to do that without compromising the function.